# Sum of torques acting on car wheels

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, torque, free-body-diagram

lets say we have a car parked on a slope and its in balance. There is a torque acting on the wheels pointing down, therefore there needs to be another force which causes a torque pointing up in order to prevent the wheels from rolling. Which force does this job?

Comment: Parking brake, or the park pawl when you shift into **P**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static friction on the wheels causes a torque, this torque needs to be reacted upon by something mechanical for the car to remain stationary. This something is the parking brake, or the park pawl which locks the gears when shifting into park (**P** position).

Static friction is necessary to balance out the component of weight that is along the ramp. Without it, the car would slide downhill, and without the torque reaction the car would roll donwhill.